# Disable client side form validation in ASP.NET Core

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I disable client-side form validation in my ASP.NET Core 1.1 app? But I need the server-side one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you just remove the javascript for jquery.unobtrusive.validation.js

In the VS project templates that is in _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml

Comment: This solves part of the problem but still generates the `data-val` attributes instead of `maxlength`, `required`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

You do this in your ConfigureServices class in your Startup file:

```
services.AddMvc().AddViewOptions(options => 
    options.HtmlHelperOptions.ClientValidationEnabled = false);
```

This will work for the attributes generated by tag helpers.

Comment: @Octopus in my case is working properly on the first try. Are you sure about the Startup.cs configuration?

Comment: @T-moty this has been solved in a recent update of .Net Core, so probably you use such a version. See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7576

Answer (score 1):

In Razor Pages

```
services.Configure<HtmlHelperOptions>(o => o.ClientValidationEnabled = false);
```

See [Disable client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#disable-client-side-validation)